# Mixing encapsulated polymer js components with dart

Tags: dart, polymer

I have spend some time reading and doing tutorials on dart,polymer, web components. I am wondering the following:

If a (polymer) web component is a encapsulated piece of UI. Why is it not possible (or easier) to use a web components, with perhaps a JS script encapsulated, in a dart project. By just letting the web component do what is suppose to do using for example JS, but hooking it up (with event binding or querySelector)  with a dart class which can manipulate it.

Comment: It's supposed to work this way. Do you have a concrete problem?

Comment: The other way around is not yet supported (use a Polymer.dart component in a JS project)

Comment: No I don't have concrete problem atm. But during my readings I somehow made this assumption. Very glad to hear that this is not true ! Thank you.

Comment: There is  https://github.com/dart-lang/custom-element-apigen which makes it even easier to integrate Polymer.js elements. Dart core- and paper-elements are built this way. It hides most dart-js-interop and provides a nice Dart API. You don't need this when you interact only through published attributes but many Polymer elements have fields and methods which can only be accessed from JavaScript (or dart-js-interop)

Comment: I've experimented with this technique (building the UI with Polymer JS components and manipulating them from Dart). There's some example code here: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/tree/master/lib/polymer and here: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/blob/master/lib/mobile/mobile.dart. It works well; I like the mix of working closely to the polymer JS components, having access to the (very nice) paper / material design components, and being able to work with and manipulate your UI from Dart.